# Twitter auto shorten URL not working

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to add custom tweet button to my website and all is well but it is not shortening the URL. I am using URL query string instead of javascript. Is that the case?

```
<a class="btn btn-tweet" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?text='.$title.'&url='.$url.'&via='.$user.'&wrap_links=true">Twitter</a>
```

I have read some API document and saying above 19 characters twitter shorten url itself. Just wonder why it is not converting with this.

I am also having trouble to open in popup instead of new window. Does this all possible without adding any separate javascript code but directly inline in anchor tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't be visibly shortened in the compose window, but the compose window does detect URLs and adjusts the character count accordingly. Try pasting a huge long URL - it'll only use up 22 characters in the count.

Do note that Twitter shortens **all** URLs, even when "shortening" actually makes them longer. For example, "http://bit.ly" will use up 22 characters (not 19), not 13.

Comment: I understand that but it is not even shortening after posing to the twitter. Also it is counting long URL characters while in the posting form and that creates problem with the counter

Comment: Give us an example, then. And note that it'll appear unshortened on Twitter.com and in most clients. If you hover over it it'll be a `t.co` link.

Comment: Sure! what exactly I should share?

Comment: Share us an example `https://twitter.com/share?text='.$title.'&url='.$url.'&via='.$user.'&wrap_links=true` URL that isn't working with filled-in parameters.

Comment: Also, post it to Twitter and link us to the post.

Comment: I have cross checked on twitter and found its been shorten in this way.. `4/the-item-title-and-sublinks...` so is it right?

Comment: Yes, Twitter will truncate the link, add `...`, and if you hover over it it's going to be a `t.co` shortened link underneath.

Comment: I see.. so there is another issue within. Since twitter allow only 140chrs and I am sharing title and link so how can I check the total characters and limit it before sharing?

Comment: Again, links will always use up 22 characters (or 23 if they're HTTPS). Thus, you've got 117 characters for a title, one space, and then a 22 character link.

Comment: So this means I should control title length within the php before send it to the twitter. Right?

Comment: Sure, or just don't worry about it and let the user sort it out. Depends on how often your titles go over 117 characters.

Comment: I see. okay thanks a lot for your help and clear my confusion.

Answer (score 22):

I was hung up on this and realized I was trying to shorten "http://localhost:5000/blog/url" which t.co is unable to do.

Change to a real, non-localhost URL and it worked fine.

Comment: So twitter detects localhost and doesn't shorten it. Nice one!

Comment: Was driving me crazy when testing...This should be on top of this page :D